# Cannot use newid() and a variable in a query with Azure SQL Datawarehouse - why?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

When I try to run an insert statement like below on Azure SQL DW I always get the following error message

*Msg 107085, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 107085;The query encountered a data consistency issue that prevents further execution. This issue could have been caused by use of non-deterministic operations in the query. Rewrite the failed query and re-execute it*

```
insert into dbo.LoadLogs (Id, LoadDescription, RecordCount, LoadDate)
    select newid() as Id, @LoadDescription, @RecordCount, @LoadDate;
```

Comment: I am able to get that code to work if I move the newid() into a variable, but I have other insert into select statements with newid that work on Azure SQL DW consistently (but they don't have the variables in them).  Would love to no why this one has a consistency issue - still seems like a combination of variables and newid() call, but no explanation.

Comment: Always happening is something wrong.Can you also please raise a ticket with azure team,i am not able to repro the same issue in sql azure

Comment: I recommend moving this to DBA.SE as well

Answer (score 2):

The SQL DW service today doesn't support non-deterministic functions in DML statements. So your NEWID() call in the INSERT statement isn't supported (the error message is a bit misleading - we can improve that). Adding support is in our backlog. You can always file a request in our feedback forum:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse

For now, you'll need to create a local variable for your GUID generations. Something like:

```
DECLARE @newidentifier UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

SET @newidentifier = NEWID();

insert into dbo.LoadLogs (Id, LoadDescription, RecordCount, LoadDate)
    select @newidentifier, @LoadDescription, @RecordCount, @LoadDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of our NewId(),also the datatype of all fields, and the value before insertion happen.

Maybe your ID is a primary key and auto incremental,your query is no longer happen and it can't be done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is in Azure SQL DW which is an MPP system that doesn't support primary keys or identity columns.

Comment: Ok man,, sorry for that.. im just thinking some posibilities that could help you.